# Django downloading a file

Tags: python, django

i have a db i made it with Django, and with the models.CharField I created the path how the users going to upload a file in their post. in `MEDIA_URL = "/media/"`
but i tried to let the user download the content (the file) throw a link or just a click. how can i do that!
i have a multiple files name in my models.py like this:

```
files_Tensile = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
files_Charpy = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
files_Modulus = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
Diagramm_Hohen_Temp = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
files_Metallo = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
Gefüge = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
Diagramm_Wärmebehandlung=models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D")
files_Density = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="chapters/%Y/%m/%D"
```

the views.py:

```
def download(request, path):
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
                return 

response
    raise Http404
```

in the html:

```
<td><a  href="media/files_Density/download"> Download Files</a></td>
```

ulrs.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView,
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", PostListView.as_view(), name="Blog-home"),
    path("user/<str:username>", UserPostListView.as_view(), name="user-posts"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
    path("post/new/", PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/update/", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/delete/", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path("about/", views.about, name="Blog-about"),
    path("search_post/", views.search_post, name="search-post"),
    path('download/<str:path>', views.download, name='download'),    
]
```

I get the error, Page not found (404). can anyone please explain how to fix this?

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: Can you share the urls.py file?

Comment: yeah, its in the post theres

Answer (score 0):

the `MEDIA_URL = "/media/"` is for a user to view user created files after uploaded

the easiest way to download a file on click (that is on the same server as the webpage) is to add in the html a tag a download attribute

in the html

```
<td><a  href="fileURLGoesHere" download> Download Files</a></td>
```

Comment: if i did that, thats mean i have to do it for every file is going to be upload it?
is theres anyway to set one cod for every file

Comment: you can get the url to the file from the file field by accessing the filefield.url in the template use `{{files_Modulus.url}}`

Comment: great, so it worked. how can i return the file default when the user delete his file